# Why my bootstrap carousel slider cannot move?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello guys so I'm trying to use carousel from Bootstrap by just copying the code without changing anything, but for some reason the carousel didn't work (can't move to next slide). Anyone knows how to fix this? and also, does anyone know how to make the carousel size smaller? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Script for Font Awesome, jquerycdn -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The cdn for `bootstrap.min.js` is missing without it the effect will not happen

Comment: add` <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: ohh sorry, i forgot to put some of the script on my post.. i already edit my post, please check again. thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary to get include jquery cdn also along with bootstrap js? Just wondering

Comment: maybe, i get this from bootstrap 4 template.. btw how can i change the color of previous and next button ? any idea?

Comment: For colour change just add the appropriate color classes dynamically or manually. The classes would be `bg-white, bg-success, bg-danger` etc. Check bootstrap documentation for more

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/540518/pexels-photo-540518.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/540518/pexels-photo-540518.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/540518/pexels-photo-540518.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```